# No implementation found for method getAll on channel dev.fluttercommunity.plus/package_info

Tags: windows, flutter, debugging, package, package-info

I'm trying to debug a project for windows, and I'm having this problem:
It runs and stops at Parse().initialize giving the error

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel dev.fluttercommunity.plus/package_info)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:175:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:377:43)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelPackageInfo.getAll (package:package_info_plus_platform_interface/method_channel_package_info.dart:13:17)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      PackageInfo.fromPlatform (package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart:36:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Parse.initialize (package:parse_server_sdk_flutter/parse_server_sdk.dart:67:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      initializeParse (package:spa/main.dart:73:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      main`enter code here` (package:spa/main.dart:27:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I've tried everything, clean and pub get. When it runs for the web it works normally, it just gives an error when I go to run for windows

Comment: Could you provide the code that is not working for you? Here is [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Adding a new package usually doesn't work with hot-reload, have you made sure that you are doing a complete re-run of the app?

Comment: It runs and stops at Parse().initialize giving the error [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel dev.fluttercommunity.plus/package_info)

I've tried everything, clean and pub get. When it runs for the web it works normally, it just gives an error when I go to run for windows

Comment: I'm getting this same error after making a new Parse app. Parse app that I've been working on for months connecting to the same Parse server with the same version does NOT have an issue. Both apps are using the same version of Flutter and boilerplate code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

To solve the problem I had to add the package_info_plus_windows plugin

```
flutter pub add package_info_plus_windows
```

Then in the Parse method I added this

```
import 'package:package_info_plus_platform_interface/package_info_data.dart';

Future<void> initializeParse() async {
  const appId = 'xxxx';
  const clientKey = 'xxxxx';
  const serverURL = 'xxxx';
  const liveQueryUrl = 'xxxx';
  PackageInfoData packageInfoWindows = await PackageInfoWindows().getAll();

  await Parse().initialize(
    appId,
    serverURL,
    clientKey: clientKey,
    liveQueryUrl: liveQueryUrl,
    autoSendSessionId: true,
    debug: true,
    appName: packageInfoWindows.appName,
    appVersion: packageInfoWindows.version,
    appPackageName: packageInfoWindows.packageName,
  );
}
```

Comment: Good stuff. Worked for me. Replace "windows" with "linux" if you are building a Linux Desktop version.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `PackageInfoData` was not accessible so my solution was:

```
 var packageInfoWindows = await PackageInfoWindows().getAll();

  await Parse().initialize(
      keyApplicationId,
      keyParseServerUrl,
      clientKey: keyClientKey,
      autoSendSessionId: true,
    debug: true,
    appName: packageInfoWindows.appName,
    appVersion: packageInfoWindows.version,
    appPackageName: packageInfoWindows.packageName

  );
```